# Arrangement System in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request, rethinkdb

I want to make arrangements system between users, where a user can make an arrangement with another user, and that user can read the properties of the arrangement like `date` and `discreption` etc..

This is the migration:

```
Schema::create('arrangements', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('acceptor_id')->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(false);
        $table->dateTime('start_at');
        $table->dateTime('end_at');
        $table->longText('discreption');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have set the relationships between the models `User` and `Arrangement`

I am able to get the confiremd and unconfiremd arrangements as well, but I can't let the user accept that specific arrangement which was sent by another user.

I want also a method where I can check if there is a request pending, and another method, to check if the arrangement is already confiremd.

These are my methods:

```
public function acceptedArrangements()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Arrangement::class)
        ->where('confirmed', true);
}

public function unAcceptedArrangements()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Arrangement::class)
        ->where('confirmed', false);
}

public function arrangements()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Arrangement::class);
}

public function createArrangemenet(User $user)
{
    $authID = Auth::user()->id;

    $arrangement = Arrangement::create([
        'user_id' => $authID,
        'acceptor_id' => $user->id,
        'confirmed' => false,
        'start_at' => request('start_at'),
        'end_at' => request('end_at'),
        'discreption' => request('discreption')
    ]);        
}
```

Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: Well, you will have to create a function like `acceptArrangement()` . You already have the functions needed to show to the user the pending/confirmed ones. All you have to do is add a button which calls `acceptArrangement()` or `declineArrangement()`. Have you tried anything?

Comment: That is the thing. I don't exactly know how to define these functions```acceptArrangement()``` ```declineArrangement()```

Comment: First, before writing any code, think about it. You want a user to be able to accept an arrangement ( a pending request ). Every pending request has a specific ID(`id`), the sender (`acceptor_id`) and state(`confirmed`). So when accepting, you will have to take that request, change the properties etc